# How datasets are structured in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

In my first TensorFlow project, I have a big dataset (1M elements) which contains 8 categories of elements, with each category, has a different number of elements of course. I want to split the big dataset into 10 exclusive small datasets, with each of them having approximately 1/10 of each category. (This is for 10-fold cross-validation purposes.)

Here is how I do.
I wind up having 80 datasets, with each category having 10 small datasets, then I randomly sample data from 80 of them by using sample_from_datasets. However, after some steps, I met a lot of warning saying "DirectedInterleave selected an exhausted input:36" where 36 can be some other integer numbers.

The reason I want to do `sample_from_datasets` is that I tried to do shuffle the original dataset. Even though shuffle only 0.4 x total elements, it still takes a long long time to finish (about 20mins).

My questions are
1. based on my case, any good advice on how to structure the datasets?
2. is it normal to have a long shuffling time? any better solution for shuffling?
3. why do I get this DirectIngerleave selected an exhausted input:  warning? and what does it mean?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your **whole datasets** into Training, Testing and Validation categories. As you have 1M data, you can split like this: 60% training, 20% testing and 20% validation. Splitting of datasets is completely up to you and your requirements. But normally maximum data is used for training the model. Next, the rest of the datasets can be used for testing and validation. 
As you have **ten class** datasets, split each category into Training, Testing and Validation categories.

Let, you have A, B, C and D categories data. Split your data "A", "B", "C", and "D" like below:

'A'- 60 % for training 20% testing and 20% validation

'B'- 60 % for training 20% testing and 20% validation

'C'- 60 % for training 20% testing and 20% validation

'D'- 60 % for training 20% testing and 20% validation

Finally merge all the A, B, C and D training, testing and validation datasets.